# JPA, HIBERNATE. How to get next value from @TableGenerator

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity class with below primary key generation strategy

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
@TableGenerator(name = "USERGENERATOR", table = "my_sequences", pkColumnName = "sequence_name", pkColumnValue = "user_id", valueColumnName = "next_value")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "USERGENERATOR")
protected Integer id;
```

This was working fine until a new requirement came up where I need to insert a new row using a native query. The primary key column doesn't use auto_increment because of Entity Inheritance strategy (@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)) in place.

I was wondering if there is a way to ask the table generator for the next value using the EntityManager.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access the `@TableGenerator` through any public API, but getting the next value with native SQL is easy. Just use these two queries:

```
-- get the current value
select next_value from my_sequences where sequence_name = 'user_id';
-- update value
update my_sequences set next_value = next_value + 1;
```

There is a risk of conflict if `@TableGenerator` fetches the next value at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "USERGENERATOR")` by `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` like this when you add a new element, it will add 1 auto

Comment: Because this is for your id which should be unique @chege And you can use `strategy = GenerationType.AUTO` too, it will  incrementing auto